# Clojure: immutability and persistence

Tags: clojure, persistence, immutability

Every textbook says that Clojure data structures are 'immutable and persistent'. They go different lengths explaining the concept, but so far I failed to figure out what is the difference between immutability and persistence. Is there an entity persistent but mutable? or immutable but not persistent?

Comment: It may be helpful to look up the definition of "Persistent Data Structure" - it's a general CS thing that Clojure did not invent or coin [persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)

Answer (score 5):

Immutable means that the value can't be changed and persistence means that the path to the value is copied if the value already exists within the program. Clojure uses this as a part of it's structural sharing implementation. If the data doesn't exist, it's created. If the data exists, the new data builds on the old version of the data without altering or removing it.

Atoms are persistent but safely mutable.

```
user> (def +a+ (atom 0))
#'user/+a+
user> @+a+
0
user> (swap! +a+ inc)
1
user> @+a+
1
```

Transients are mutable but should be made persistent after mutation

```
user> (def t (transient []))
#'user/t
user> (conj! t 1)
#<TransientVector clojure.lang.PersistentVector$TransientVector@658ee462>
user> (persistent! t)
[1]
```

Understanding Clojure's Persistent Vectors, pt. 1 =>
http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1

Persistent data structure => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure

Persistent Data Structures and Managed References =>
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey

Answer (score 4):

*Purely Functional Data Structures* by Chris Okasaki refers to an article [1] which appears to contain the original definition of the term *persistent*:

> Ordinary data structures are *ephemeral* in the sense that making a change to the structure destroys the old version, leaving only the new one. … We call a data structure *persistent* if it supports access to multiple versions. The structure is *partially persistent* if all versions can be accessed but only the newest version can be modified, and *fully persistent* if every version can be both accessed and modified.

[1] James R. Driscoll, Neil Sarnak, Daniel D. Sleator, and Robert E. Tarjan. Making data structures persistent. *Journal of Computer and System Sciences*, 38(1):86–124, February 1989.

Answer (score 1):

Immutable implies persistent, but persistent does not imply immutable. So you could have something that's persistent but not immutable.

An example of a mutable and persistent data structure is Java's [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Persistence does *not* imply shared structure, nor does it say anything about performance. Of course, shared structure and good performance are both highly desirable, and are both provided by Clojure's persistent data structures. But it would be quite possible to create something that had no structure sharing and awful performance (see `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, for example ;-)) but was still persistent.

Answer (score -1):

Basically immutable == can't be changed, and persistent == immutable, with shared structure.

If I have a language where arrays can't be changed, then arrays are immutable.  To "change" the array, I must create a new array and copy every element (except the one(s) to be changed) into the new array.  This makes any update O(n), where n is the number of elements in the array.  This is obviously inefficient for large n.

On the other hand, if I use a persistent data structure instead of an array, then instead of copying every element every time the data structure is "altered", the new version shares most of the same structure with the old one.

The details depend on the structure, but often usually there is a tree involved.  If the tree is balanced, replacing an element means creating new copies of nodes along the path from the root to the leaf containing the element.  The rest of the nodes are shared with the original version.  The length of this path is O(n log(n)).  Since the nodes are O(1) size, the entire operation takes O(n log(n)) time and extra space.

Note that not all persistent structures support the same operations efficiently.  In Clojure, for example, Lists are singly-linked lists.  You can efficiently add and remove elements to/from the front, but that's about it.  Vectors, on the other hand, allow you to efficiently get any element and add/remove elements at the back.